# Trying to make CSS class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS class with the following:

```
var not_cursor = $('<style>#NOT_CURSOR { CURSOR: NONE; BACKGROUND: URL("images/NOT1.png") NO-REPEAT LEFT TOP; 
                  POSITION: ABSOLUTE;
                  DISPLAY: NONE;
                  TOP: 0;
                  LEFT: 0;
                  Z-INDEX: 10000;}</style>');
$('html > head').append(not_cursor);
```

And then in another file I try accessing $('#NOT_CURSOR') but I get an error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

And it's telling me this occurs on line 1. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `$('head').append(not_cursor);`? Also, the error is in line 1 because it comes from the element dynamically added to the DOM, not in the script. And also, are you trying to select a class `#NOT_CURSOR` with an ID selector `$('#NOT_CURSOR')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try keeping it all on one line or concatening the separate line chunks.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XuWge/)**.

OR, use the multi-line escape trick: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eUXpq/)**.

```
var not_cursor = $('<style>#NOT_CURSOR { CURSOR: NONE; BACKGROUND: URL("images/NOT1.png") NO-REPEAT LEFT TOP; \
                  POSITION: ABSOLUTE; \
                  DISPLAY: NONE; \
                  TOP: 0; \
                  LEFT: 0; \
                  Z-INDEX: 10000;}</style>');
$('html > head').append(not_cursor);
```

​